# « y arriver » et « en arriver à »

Tags: sens, expressions, choix-de-mot

J'ai des difficultés à comprendre la différence entre *y arriver* et *en arriver à*. On m'a donné les deux exemples suivants :

> Si nous travaillons fort, nous allons y arriver.

(y arriver = réussir ?)

> Après plusieurs réflexions, j’en arrive à choisir ce bleu.

Qu'est-ce que *en arriver à* veut dire ?

Answer (score 5):

« **Arriver à** faire quelque chose »  est effectivement synonyme de « réussir ».

> Si nous travaillons dur nous allons arriver à finir la maison avant l'été.

Le pronom personnel *y* remplace de complément d'objet indirect « à finir la maison » :

> Nous allons y arriver.

On peut aussi dire :

> Nous allons y parvenir.
>   Nous allons réussir.

« **En arriver à** » veut dire « finir par faire quelque chose » ou « décider ».

> Après réflexion, j'ai fini par (j'ai décidé de) choisir ce bleu.

Answer (score 2):

“En arriver à” is a fixed verb phrase meaning “to be at (or coming to) the point of …”
So in your sentence 2, in the present tense as it is, it would mean to me:

> After much reflection, I am at (or I am coming to) the point of
>   choosing this blue.

To me, the actual act of choosing has not quite yet been finalized, but it will come soon.

Your translation of "y arriver = réussir" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Il me semble que « y arriver » veut dire « **arriver à** (une destination) », tandis que « en arriver » veut dire « **arriver de** (un point initial ou intermédiaire) ».

Donc vous avez « y arriver (au but) », et « en arriver (de, commençant par, au moyen de, à travers, les réflexions) ».

Le premier dirige son regard vers le futur (le but), le deuxième se souvient du passé (le chemin parcouru).

Answer (score 0):

Le sens premier de

> *arriver* : toucher la rive, le bord ; parvenir près du port, au port.

L'idée de la fin d'un voyage, d'un parcours intellectuel :

> - *y arriver* : (*y* est ici le port) l'endroit qui est la destination prévue du voyage ; c'est un déplacement physique où le regard est tourné vers le but, c'est une démonstration que l'on valide.
> - *en arriver* : À la fin d'un parcours dont on ne connaît pas forcement la destination (cette dernière n'est pas forcément désirée), on est déjà sur la rive, on a déjà accosté, et on constate ce qui nous a amené ici ; c'est la conclusion d'un cheminement démonstratif construit pas à pas.